# How to apply a method for ag-Grid data in angular?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to apply a method for ag-Grid data. Here my intention is after loading data into the grid, when we click any data on grid, method should be call. 
Usually If it is table data we can apply like this

```html
<tbody (click)="methodName()">
-------------------------
</tbody>
```

But for ag-Grid data I couldn't find the way to apply method. If any one have idea please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah got it, ag-Grid having some inbuilt events. So we can use those events.
In my case I have applied click functionality for every cell.
(cellDoubleClicked)="onCellDoubleClicked($event)"

or If we want to apply for row also we can implement like this.
onRowDoubleClicked: doSomething

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, there are a lot of methods you could hook into to get a result similar to what you want. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/

If you really want to listen for a click **anywhere** in the grid, you could wrap it in a dom element that has a click listener

```
<div (click)="methodName()">
   <!-- your grid markup goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: @Keenam Diggs Thanks for your answer, but I need to apply event for only grid data not entire grid like headers and all not required.

Comment: Then perhaps you should hook into `rowClicked()` or `cellClicked()` and filter what data gets processed based on whatever conditions you require.

Comment: Yeah got it, there are some inbuilt events we can use directly for grid options. Thanks for your referral info.